# Position absolute não funciona no IOS

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou tentando alinhar um botão no final de um `ion-item`
Meu `css` do botão é:

```css
position: absolute !important;
right: 0%;
bottom: 0;
```

e o resultado no Android é:

[image: VEJA NO BLOG]

Porém no `IOS` o botão simplesmente não aparece, ou aparece em alguns itens no meio do `ion-item`, as vezes acima, mas não aparece conforme no Android.

> Há algum problema com `position: absolute` para `IOS`?
>   Estou fazendo algo errado?
>  
>   Há uma maneira melhor de posicionar um botão ao fim do ion-item?

Usando `item-end` ele consome toda a área do botão, não deixando espaço acima para os textos.  Obrigado por qualquer ajuda =)

Comment: O problema pode estar na classe que você está inserindo o css. Sugiro usar o `ionic serve --lab` e inspecionar o elemento para ver se o css que você incluiu está sendo considerado.

Comment: Obrigado por responder @Renata, mas eu não costumo usar ionic serve --lab, pois é sempre me mostra o mesmo visual para Android e IOS.  no caso esse botão aparece no dispositivo Android, mas não corretamente no IOS.  Usando ionic serve --lab ambos estão iguais e corretos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver adicionando em meu css:

```
float: right;
```